# simple onclick applied on <a> not working IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a simple list as follows:

```
<div class="settingButton"><a href="#"></a>
     <div class="subManu">
           <ul>
               <li><a onclick="alert('clicked!!')" href="#">Default Categories</a></li>
               <li><a onclick="alert('clicked!!')" href="#">Wizard</a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I do not see the alerts on clicking the links! It works fine in Chrome, but not in IE and FF. I used this same structure without assigning class and it works as expected. Maybe the problem is with the CSS, but I am not sure what. Here is the CSS for the dropdown,

```
.settingButton { 
   background:url(/mobiledoc/jsp/dashboard/images/settings.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
   width:25px; 
   height:37px; 
   float:left; 
   position:absolute;
   right:13px;
   top:-30px;
}
.settingButton a {
   display:block;
   width:25px;
   height:37px;
}
.settingButton:hover {
   background:url(/mobiledoc/jsp/dashboard/images/settingsHover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.settingButton:active {
   background:url(/mobiledoc/jsp/dashboard/images/settingsActive.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.settingButton div.subManu {
   display:none;
   height:100px;
}
.settingButton:hover div.subManu {
   background:url(/mobiledoc/jsp/dashboard/images/subNavArrow.png) no-repeat right 3px;    
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   z-index:99;
   right:0;
   width:250px;
   height:50px;
   display:block;
   padding:13px 0 0 0;
}
div.subManu ul {
   display:block;
   background:url(/mobiledoc/jsp/dashboard/images/dropDownMidBg.png) repeat-x;
   border-left:#547b9a 1px solid;
   border-right:#547b9a 1px solid;
   height:29px;
   padding:0 0 0 7px;
}
div.subManu ul li {
   width:110px;
   float:left;
   margin:0 5px;
   display:block;
   height:29px;
}
div.subManu ul li a {
   display:inline;
   color:#ffffff;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:12px;
   font-weight:normal;
   line-height:28px;
}
div.subManu ul li a:hover {
   color:#b7f630;
}
div.subManu ul li.active-manu a {
   color:#b7f630;
}
```

I have gone through different question but didn't find any relevant answers. Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Comment: could you make a fiddle?

Comment: can't see anything immediately wrong with it, except that the `<div>` inside the `<ul>` isn't valid. That shouldn't cause the problems you're seeing though.

Comment: @Spudley: I used the same structure without the classes and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm sure it works; all I'm saying is that `<div>` inside `<ul>` is invalid HTML. I don't think it's likely to be related to this issue, and browsers will generally deal with it okay, but it's not strictly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a link, don't use an A element, use a button or styled span instead, e.g.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .clickable:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
 </style>
 ...
 <span class="clickable">thing to click</span>
```

Anyhow, the preferred method for links is:

```
<a href="http://link for script-disabled browsers" 
   onclick="myFunction(); return false;">...</a>
```

Comment: ... The preferred method? :-)

Comment: Rob you were right, I really didn't need an A element. Using a span instead did the trick! thanks a lot :)
Though, I still don't get what was wrong with using an anchor tag??

Comment: A link tells users that they are going to navigate somewhere, a button says something other than navigation will occur. It also removes issues with what to do with the href attribute and cancelling navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZK4b/)

You will notice I only made two changes to your code.

The first change is to include background color for the hover div.

The second change is to make the font words viewable on the white background since the font's are white themselves.

To see both click events working, hover over the black rectangle in the top right corner and you will see the two links that will pop up and allow the alert to invoke when clicked.

The bottom line is ***there is nothing wrong*** with your ***code***, it's just you need to hover to access the clickable links.

***Disclaimer:** It's for the Question only and doesn't cover other things like the preferred method for anchor links. ;-)*

Comment: I have the images mentioned in the url. On hover I can access the links as well, but the problem still persists...I do not know how your code works and mine doesn't! They are the same!! Do you think that the images may be causing the problem?

Comment: Here is the same [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZK4b/1/) but I have images replaced. Same issue, works with no problems. That said, there is something else the matter that is affecting the anchor tags. Link to website?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try something like this instead:

```
    <a href="javascript: alert('clicked!!')">Default Categories</a>
```

Comment: -1. Links should go somewhere useful, an onclick listener should be an alternative or complimentary action. Don't use the javascript pseudoprotocol.